# create new columns with info of other column on python pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a grouped dataframe

```
 id  num  week  
101   23   7     3
           8     1
           9     2
102   34   8     4
           9     1
          10     2
       ...
```

And I need to create new columns and have a dataFrame like this

```
 id  num  7  8  9  10
101   23  3  1  2   0
102   34  0  4  1   2
        ...
```

As you may see, the values of the week column turned into several columns.

I may also have the input dataFrame not grouped, or with `reset_index`,  like this:

```
 id  num  week  
101   23   7     3
101   23   8     1
101   23   9     2
102   34   8     4
102   34   9     1
102   34  10     2
       ...
```

but I don't know with which would be easier to start.

**Notice** that `id` and `num` are both keys

Comment: Try the `pivot` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use unstack() and fillna(0) to not have NaNs.

Let's load the data:

```
id  num  week  val
101   23   7     3
101   23   8     1
101   23   9     2
102   34   8     4
102   34   9     1
102   34   10    2

s = pd.read_clipboard(index_col=[0,1,2], squeeze=True)
```

Notice I have set the index to be id, num and week. If you haven't yet, use `set_index`.

Now we can unstack: move from the index (rows) to the columns. By default it does it to the last level in line, which is `week` here, but you could specify it using `level=-1` or `level='week'`

```
s.unstack().fillna(0)
```

Note that as pointed out by @piRsquared you can do `s.unstack(fill_value=0)` to do it in one go.

[image: result]

Comment: you can use `fill_value` in `unstack`  `df.unstack(fill_value=0)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I added it as a note for future reference.